# Python CPLEX warm starts from infeasible solution

Tags: python, linear-programming, cplex

I currently have an (integer) LP problem solved which has, amongst others, the following mathematical constraint as pseudocode.

```
Packages_T1 + Packages_T2 + Packages_T3 + RPackages = 25
```

It represents three package trucks (T1, T2 and T3) to each of which packages can be assigned plus a residual/spilled package variable which is used in the objective function. The current value of 25 represents the total package demand.

Lets say I want to re-solve this problem but change the current demand of 25 packages to 35 packages. When I warm start from the previous solution with 25 packages CPLEX errors out in stating that the provided solution is infeasible: which makes perfect sense. However, it subsequently fails to repair the previous solution even though the most straight-forward way to do this would be to "up" the `RPackages` variable for each of these constraints.

My question is whether there is any possibility to still use the information from the previously solved problem as a warm start to the new one. Is there a way to, for example, drop all `RPackages` from the solution and have them recalculated to fit the new constraint right-hand side? A "last resort" effort I thought of would be to manually recalculate all these `RPackages` values myself and replace them in the old solution but a more automated solution to this problem would be preferred. I am using the standard CPLEX Python API for reference.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even if the warmstart is not feasible CPLEX can use some information.

Let me use the zoo example from

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

warmstart=mdl.new_solution()
warmstart.add_var_value(nbbus40,4)
warmstart.add_var_value(nbbus30,0)
mdl.add_mip_start(warmstart)


sol=mdl.solve(log_output=True)

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

gives

```
Warning:  No solution found from 1 MIP starts.
Retaining values of one MIP start for possible repair.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift reply. Those final two messages are indeed what I also observe when currently warm-starting my problems. Are you aware of any method to validate whether CPLEX actually uses (some parts of) the infeasible solution provided at the start?

Comment: if you write warmstart.add_var_value(nbbus40,8) then you ll see in the log "1 of 1 MIP starts provided solutions.
MIP start 'm1' defined initial solution with objective 4000.0000."

Comment: That makes sense, given that the value of nbbus40 = 8 satisfies the sole constraint in the model and hence provides a feasible solution. This has also worked for me in the past when restarting the same problem from an existing solution. In my new case however the existing warm start solution is infeasible in the new problem due to the equality constraint described in my original question. As a result I feel that CPLEX simply disregards the information from the .sol file and starts from scratch even though this does not feel optimal. Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: You may use •Level 4 MIPStartRepair: CPLEX attempts to repair the MIP startif it is infeasible,according to the parameter that sets the frequency to try to repairinfeasible MIP start, CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_RepairTries (that is, IloCplex::Param::MIP::Limits::RepairTries).  in mdl.add_mip_start(warmstart,effort_level=4)

Comment: I have implemented this in my code, but to no avail. It still prompts me with the messages that no solution has been found from the MIP start(s) and that CPLEX will retain one for possible repair. I'll try to edit my MIP start file such that it complies with the new constraint right-hand side and if that fails just run the program from scratch for now. Thank you very much for your efforts!